# OnCheckedChangeListener for switch not working | Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I use this code with a switch to check if the listener is working. The problem is that the application always logs that the "Switch State" is true. This also reflects in the behaviour when using the commented out code.

```
Switch mainNetworkSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.networkMainSwitch);

mainNetworkSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean  isChecked) {

                if(isChecked = true){
                    //notificationManager.cancel(1);
                    Log.v("Switch State=", "True");
                }else{
                    //notificationManager.notify(2, notificationWarning);
                    Log.v("Switch State=", "False");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` checks for the equality of primitives. So your `if` statement should use `==`, not `=` (or just use `if(isChecked) {...}`)

Comment: Thank you! If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: This question is more of a simple syntax error (a reason for closure) and there are many questions that this one could be closed as a duplicate for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparison, a variable we use double equal sign.

```
if(isChecked = true)
```

Change to

```
if(isChecked == true)
```